# Author Link Not Displaying

Tags: author, tags

I have used this with "echo" as its outside the loop i believe to the author of the post as a link, however its not displaying as a link?

```
<h2 class="sidebarheaders">Random Posts By You </h2>
<br/>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
Written by: 
<?php echo the_author_link(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`setup_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/setup_postdata) function if you want to use `the_author_link` with custom loop. Do it like this:

```
<h2 class="sidebarheaders">Random Posts By You </h2>
<br/>
<?php
$rand_posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date' ) );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post );

    ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    Written by: <?php echo the_author_link(); 

endforeach;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Don't forget to call [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_reset_postdata) to restore the $post global to the current post in the main query.